# Writing and solving a recurrence for this algorithm that counts prime numbers?

Tags: math, big-o, computer-science, recurrence

I'm studying for a test and I came across this question, I'm not too great at this course and I'm completely stumped by it. I would really appreciate some help!

> Suppose you have access to an algorithm isprime(n) which runs in time
>   O(n) (say, a brute force checking divisibility by all numbers less
>   than n). The following code calculates the number of primes less than
>   or equal to its input argument.
>
> ```
> boolean numprimes(int n) {
>     if (n == 1) {
>         return 0;
>     } else if (isprime(n)) {
>         return numprimes(n − 1) + 1;
>     } else {
>         return numprimes(n − 1);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The goal is to analyze the runtime of num primes. Achieve this goal by
>   doing the following:
>
> (a) Write a recursive definition for T (n) the running time of the
>   algorithm on an instance of size n.
>
> (b) Solve the recursive definition
>   of T (n) to acquire a closed form using the method of repeated
>   substitutions, making a guess, proving the guess by induction, and the
>   finally deducing a closed from based on your guess. Alternatively, you
>   can use repeated substitutions to guess a closed form, and prove your
>   closed form correct by induction.

Thanks a lot, I will really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hint, here's what the recurrence looks like:

> T(1) = 1
>
> T(n) = T(n - 1) + O(n)

This holds because there's always one recursive call made (on an input of size `n - 1`), and each individual call does O(n) work.

If you rewrite this as

> T(1) ≤ 1
>
> T(n) ≤ T(n - 1) + kn

You can start iterating.  As a hint, the final result should be O(n<sup>2</sup>); I'll leave the details to you.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

a) Since the test for prime is performed in O(n) time, the recurrence will be

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n)
```

b) With part a solved, the rest should be easy enough.  I can help you more if you show me what you have done to solve this.